# Show $\{x_n\}$ approaches zero "faster" than $1/n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Prove that if $\{x_n\}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence of positive numbers and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n=0$, i.e., $x_n$ approaches zero "faster" than $1/n$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \geq N$,

$$(2n)x_{2n} < 2\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}x_k < \epsilon.$$

Make a similar argument for the odd-indexed subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy's Condensation Test:

If the terms of a series $\sum x_k$ are nonnegative and decreases monotonically to $0$, the series converges if and only if $\sum 2^k x_{2^k}$ converges.

Proof: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

---

By CCT, we know that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} 2^n x_{2^n} = 0$ (because the given series is convergent).

If $2^n \le k \le 2^{n+1}$, then $x_k \le x_{2^n}$ (decreasing sequence) and then: $$kx_k \le 2^{n+1}x_{2^n} = 2(2^nx_{2^n})$$ Finally, given $\varepsilon >0$, exists $N$ such that $n>N \implies 2^nx_{2^n} < \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Same $N$ makes $$kx_k \le 2\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$ which is the required result.